# puppeteer splitwise login not wokring

Tags: puppeteer

I have tried multiple examples to get the splitwise login but unable to get it working.
Although, I'm quite new to puppeteer but login felt a simple usecase for understanding puppeteer.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const screenshot = 'login.png';
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto("https://www.splitwise.com/login", {
   waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  });
  await page.type('#user_session_email', 'atest')
  await page.type('#user_session_password', 'test')
  await page.click('[name="commit"]')
  await page.waitForNavigation()
  browser.close()
  console.log('See screenshot: ' + screenshot)
})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the page has two forms with identical ids (but different classes) and these forms have inputs with identical ids as well. You just need more specific selectors:

```js
await page.type('form.form-stacked #user_session_email', 'atest')
await page.type('form.form-stacked #user_session_password', 'test')
await page.click('form.form-stacked [name="commit"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a puppeteer issue.

It seems that javascript code in page is actively blocking triggered events somehow.

Are you able to set these values using regular javascript in the console?